# DatePicker Doesn't Work When Called Inside a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this weird problem. I am trying to initialize a datepicker inside a document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(fncInitialize);

    function fncInitialize() {
        fncBindControls();
    }

    function fncBindControls() {
         var objDate = $(this).find("input[data-datepicker='True']");
        objDate.datepicker();
    }
```

The problem is this doesn't work. The datepicker is not working. Fortunately when I reposition the element:

```
function fncInitialize() {
        var objDate = $(this).find("input[data-datepicker='True']");
        objDate.datepicker();
        fncBindControls();
    }

    function fncBindControls() { 
    }
```

This code works. But why? I just put the datepicker on another function for maintainability but it doesn't work. Do I really need to put it inside the first function of document ready?

Comment: does this `input[data-datepicker='True']` exist in the source page when you try to BindControls ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because in the second function you've lost the scope of `this`. You need to either pass it as a parameter:

```
$(document).ready(fncInitialize);

function fncInitialize() {
  fncBindControls(this);
}

function fncBindControls(el) {
  var objDate = $(el).find("input[data-datepicker='True']");
  objDate.datepicker();
}
```

Or provide a scope when you call the function:

```
function fncInitialize() {
  fncBindControls.call(this);
}
```

Comment: It works pretty well and I understand your explanation. Many thanks!